# Getting all sentItems folder emails from outlook using C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin

My app needs to iterate over all sent items and extract the To and CC.

As I understand there are 2 ways to do it:

**1. Iterating through all the items like this:**

```
inboxFolder = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as Outlook.Folder;
inboxItems = inboxFolder.Items;
```

**The problem:** 
it gets me a single page and not all sent items since the beginning of time.

**2. Iterating using table:**

```
    inboxFolder =         
    nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as 
    Outlook.Folder;
    inboxTable = inboxFolder.GetTable();
    while (!inboxTable.EndOfTable) {
        Outlook.Row inboxRow = inboxTable.GetNextRow();
    }
```

**The problem:**
the rows only contain Subject but i need To,CC too

Any help to resolve my use case using either of the methods (or other) would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A single page? Items collection contains all item in a folder. There is no concept of pages in OOM.

Comment: In my case the returned items collection contained 100 inbox messages although my full inbox has 3,000. This is exactly the number of shown items in my inbox - below them there's a link 'click for more results'... sounds like paging to me.

Comment: That is because your OST fiel is not set to sync all items. Change the sync slider to download all items in the Exchange account properties dialog.